# Is virtual machine image a good protection for source code?

Tags: virtual-machine, distribution

We have developed an application that is sold as an online service. After some time we realized that some of customers would need/prefer/require to have it installed locally on their intranet. However the application was developed using scripting language and we wouldn't want to allow clients to access the source code.

The question is: What are the technical downsides of distributing application as a virtual machine image?

Comment: You're asking me to put a virtual machine on the network that I can't see what its doing?  Not just an application, but an entire machine that I don't even have root on?

Comment: He did not ask that. But maybe you can turn your question into an answer? On the other hand, each time you install an application, open source or not, you are effectively putting something on the network that you don't have root on.

Comment: @MichaelT if you agree to put my application compiled into binary and allow it access your company network why would you be so suspicious about virtual machine? To elaborate - yes, virtual machine can contain some spying application, but same can be done with commercial software. Moreover many companies willingly install applications the source code of which the do not know and therefore those apps can do some harmful activities. Do we all know source code of Windows or Photoshop or MS Office? But still we allow those in our office. This is out of question here.

Comment: @AlexKey an application would run as a user, not have system permissions (typically).  On the other hand, a VM that runs in my network that I don't have root on - I can't patch for security, I can't monitor to make sure that unauthorized users aren't logging into it, I have difficulty preventing it form binding to addresses it shouldn't and sniffing traffic.  The security patch is a *very* important one in today's world.  Who is administrating these VMs if I don't have access to?

Comment: @MichaelT all these questions are usually (in commercial software world) solved by user agreement which basically is a contract between sides. Also there is such a thing like law. If my software would do some illegal activities my company can be in a big trouble. So once again, this topic is not considered here. I am looking for technical aspects rather than this.

Comment: What kind of customer (behavior) are you expecting that justifies these contortions? If they're *not* out to steal your code, they won't do so if the code just lies around. If they *are*, wrapping it up in a virtual machine will *at best* slow them down a bit, not prevent it or even make it unfeasible.

Comment: @delnan sorry, maybe I need better phrasing in my question. But the main issue is not stealing our source code by customer (as company), but preventing pirating this software (which is often done by individuals, rather than companies)

Comment: @AlexKey: So what's stopping me downloading your VM image and running that? Or what's stopping me from taking your VM image, booting it up, and just extracting the code? DRM is a rabbit hole, and not one which anybody here can give you a good answer to. If we could, we could sell it to you and everyone else for a lot of money, because nobody's figured it out.

Comment: @MichaelT: Like "normal" software, the VM would be expected to update itself ot to be updated, manually or by the package manager. I really don't see an effective difference between a black box labeled "VM" or a black box called "Application"; you are not abstracting enough. And the machine itself does NOT have to have root privileges onto the host machine.

Comment: @MichaelT Google will sell you a physical server preconfigured with their mapping service on it. Companies install those and we *know* Google steals your data :)

Comment: You dont say what 'scripting' language, but assuming PHP, there's ways to distribute the code in unreadable form.  A VM seems like overkill.  Another problem with a VM, in addition to those already presented, is that it may not run if your client itself is hosting in a VM.

Comment: @GrandmasterB not PHP, and how `intranet` combines with `itself hosting in a VM`? I haven't seen yet corporate intranets being a VM ;)

Comment: Then it will be fine, up until you encounter a customer who does.  Rather than finding the easy fix, you should focus instead on finding a decent solution for your language of choice.  Assuming we're not talking some home grown scripting language, there's probably some method of distributing encoded and/or obfuscated applications with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're suggesting is a variant of a [turnkey project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnkey).

On the pro side, a turnkey project:

- Can make it easier for a customer to get up and running quickly
- Shields the customer from all of the necessary configurations
- Can lower support costs because a standard image is used for the project

On the down side:

- You'll now need to maintain updates to the OS and supporting tools within your master or golden image
- You'll always have clients that want distro `baz` instead of the `foo` and `bar` that you already provide

Regarding protecting source code -- If the bulk of your company's intellectual property is encapsulated within the various configuration scripts, then this may be a decent approach to protecting that information.  You would:

1. copy the scripts on to the system that will be the master image
2. run the scripts to configure things
3. *remove* the scripts from the system
4. make copies of the master image and distribute.

This is probably only beneficial to you if there are a *lot* of configuration steps that have to be made.  If it's a trivial number of steps, then diligent customers can figure out exactly what your scripts set up for them.  There decision point for you is if there are enough configuration points so that the resource cost of recreating your scripts outweighs the financial cost of purchasing a system.

If you're hoping that you can provide a system and then keep control of the system account(s), I think you're going to have a harder time.  User privilege escalation exploits occur frequently across all operating systems, especially when someone already has log in access to the system.

In summary, I would only consider providing a turnkey system if you can remove all of the configuration scripts that you are concerned about prior to distribution.

**Additional considerations**
Any binary files you have would likely be safe from casual investigation.  Based upon the comments, it doesn't sound like you're worried about individuals with debuggers or reverse-engineering tools.

Database schemas will be exposed, and I don't think there's a lot you can do to protect those.  Whether or not the schema is *meaningful* to someone else is a different matter.  If the schema is large, obfuscation can be surprisingly effective at keeping prying eyes out of a database.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. It is not our intention to build perfect protection, but some basic would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so easy - even if it is a virtual machine, the client still would have access to its harddisk. I see no pros installing it on a VM. Better solution is to create agreement with no rights of selling You app, and "special" price for that customer - it means HIGH ENOUGH to sell Your sourcecode...

Comment: I do not understand about client having access to its harddrive, could you please show me an example how one would access data on harddrive on the VM on my ESXi or Xen server if they do not have an access to login to that instance? I am just unsure about how it can be done. If it can be done, then this definitely is a blocker for this distribution way.

Comment: Unless the disk image is encrypted in some way, I can easily mount a virtual disk image to another running VM, then peruse the contents at will.

Comment: Do You believie, thas someone is so insane, to allow You to put yous server to their server room and connect to the company's LAN ;)? try to think different - sell the app with source code - but source code costs. Why You dont believe them, they wont use Your code, and want them to believe You, that your server wont do anything wrong? TRUST and MONEY are basis for this case, thats my opinion

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Thanks, missed that. You are right, that would work only with encrypted disk.

Comment: @GregS Some companies do distribute their software this way, and pretty much successfully. This is not the question of sanity. For selling with source code, see one of my comments to the question itself. We have already an example of source code being uploaded to public access by one of customers engineers.

Comment: @AlexKey - You are absolutelly right, some do this, but, if I have physical access to a machine, I also have access to its data. THe question was "how to protect source code" (aplication is based on scripts, right?), my answer is "keep it safe or sell it" ;)